# Facing issues with inflections in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have included inflections.rb

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leaves', 'leaves'
end
```

and my controller leaves_controller.rb

```
class LeavesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @leave = Leave.new
  end

  def create
    @leave = Leave.create(leave_params)
    if @leave.errors.present?
      render :action => :new
    else
      redirect_to root_path, notice: I18n.t('leave_applied')
    end
  end

  private

  def leave_params
    params.require(:leave).permit(:start_date,:end_date)
  end
end
```

in leaves/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @leave do |f| %>
      
  <%= f.text_field :start_date, :placeholder => 'From Date',
                   :class => 'datepicker' %>

  <%= f.text_field :end_date, :placeholder => 'To Date',
                   :class => 'datepicker' %>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

So when I go to leaves/new path it gives me this error:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Leaves):
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your inflections.rb file in your application?

Comment: Please paste the code for `leaves/new` template

Comment: inside config/initializers/inflections.rb

Comment: edit my code please go through it @AmitThawait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is : when its trying to render `leaves/new` its searching for `Leaves` constant according to your new inflector.

Change it to

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.irregular 'leave', 'leaves'
end
```

Comment: But actually, it will also work if you remove this `inflection` since this is the normal case. You only need to add inflections for the irregular plurals that doesn't get converted in general.